# bluetoothctl hangs with "connect to bluetoothd"

Tags: pi-3b+, bluetooth, ubuntu

I have a Raspberry Pi 3 and I have been playing with the bluetooth functionality.

It worked for a while: I successfully paired a Windows machine with my Pi, but now it does not work anymore.

I used `bluetoothctl` to `scan on` and pair.

After a reboot, `bluetoothctl` does seem to be able to connect to `bluetoothd`.

It simply hangs.

What is the best way to debug this?

The bluetoothd daemon seems to be running fine. I am using Ubuntu Mate.